# image popup won't dismiss when I click button

Tags: ios, objective-c

So this brings up an image that is slightly transparent with an "X" button in the top right hand corner that dismisses the image. For some reason it's not working! Any ideas on how to dismiss the image?

Check the button maybe I didn't create the selector correctly...

```
#define OVERLAY_TAG 997
-(void)showTutorial
{
    UIWindow *keyWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
    UIView *overlay = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
    overlay.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    overlay.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [keyWindow addSubview:overlay];
    UITapGestureRecognizer * tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                                     action:@selector(dismissTutorial)];
    CGFloat border = 10;
    CGRect frame = overlay.bounds;

    // 20 is the status bar height (sorry for using the number)
    frame = CGRectMake(border, border + 20, frame.size.width - border * 2, frame.size.height - border * 2 - 20);

    // the black view in the example is probably a scroll view
    UIView *blackView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    blackView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    blackView.alpha = 0.7;
    [overlay addSubview:blackView];

    // add all the subviews for your tutorial
    /*UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"slide_image_3.png"];
    UIImageView* info = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    info.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 150);
    [blackView addSubview:info];*/

    UIImage* image4 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"close_img.png"];
    dismissTut = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(250, 18, 26, 26)];
    [dismissTut setBackgroundImage:image4 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [dismissTut addTarget:self action:@selector(dismissTutorial)
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [dismissTut setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES];

    [blackView addSubview:dismissTut];

    // make it appear with an animation
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                     animations:^{blackView.alpha = 0.6;}
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){[overlay addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];}];
}

-(void)dismissTutorial
{
    UIWindow *keyWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
    UIView *overlay = [keyWindow viewWithTag:OVERLAY_TAG];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                     animations:^{
                         overlay.alpha = 0.0;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         [overlay removeFromSuperview];
                     }];
}
```

Comment: is dismissTutorial get called when you press the X or not ?

Comment: Any other gestures being used on other views?

Comment: I called the method in the button action method.

Comment: I called it as [self dismissTut1];   I renamed the selector on the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a tag to your view : overlay.tag = OVERLAY_TAG;

```
-(void)showTutorial
{
    UIWindow *keyWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
    UIView *overlay = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
    overlay.tag = OVERLAY_TAG;
.....
}
```

Comment: Awesome! I though so, but couldn't quite figure it out. Thanks for the help!